# Problema com bindParam - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, pdo, bind

Estou tendo problemas com bindParam, alguém poderia me ajudar?

Tenho um código para cadastro de usuário no banco...

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

// Pega os dados do formulario
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : null;
$nascimento = isset($_POST['nascimento']) ? $_POST['nascimento'] : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : null;
$seg_senha = sha1($senha);  // Senha criptografada

// Validação bem simples, só para evitar dados vazios
if(empty($nome) || empty($nascimento) || empty($email) || empty($senha)){
    echo 'Volte e preencha todos os campos';
    exit;
}

// Insere no banco de dados
$pdo = db_connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, nasc, email, senha)
        values(:nome, :nasc, :email, :senha)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt = bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$stmt = bindParam(':nasc', $nascimento);
$stmt = bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt = bindParam(':senha', $seg_senha);

if($stmt->execute()){
    header('Location: index1.php');
}else{
    echo 'Erro ao cadastrar usuario no banco';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Quando executo me retorna o seguinte erro:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function bindParam() in C:\wamp64\www\ProjetoALPHA\core\cadastrar.php on line 23

Ele acusa erro bem no primeiro bindParam... $stmt = bindParam(':nome', $nome);

Não sei como arrumar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Tem um erro na forma como você implementou o BIND.

Onde tem `$stmt = bindParam`  deveria ser `$stmt->bindParam`

Veja exemplo abaixo:

```
<?php

require_once 'init.php';

// Pega os dados do formulario
$nome = isset($_POST['nome']) ? $_POST['nome'] : null;
$nascimento = isset($_POST['nascimento']) ? $_POST['nascimento'] : null;
$email = isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : null;
$senha = isset($_POST['senha']) ? $_POST['senha'] : null;
$seg_senha = sha1($senha);  // Senha criptografada

// Validação bem simples, só para evitar dados vazios
if(empty($nome) || empty($nascimento) || empty($email) || empty($senha)){
    echo 'Volte e preencha todos os campos';
    exit;
}

// Insere no banco de dados
$pdo = db_connect();
$sql = "INSERT INTO usuarios(nome, nasc, email, senha)
        values(:nome, :nasc, :email, :senha)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':nome', $nome);
$stmt->bindParam(':nasc', $nascimento);
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $email);
$stmt->bindParam(':senha', $seg_senha);

if($stmt->execute()){
    header('Location: index1.php');
}else{
    echo 'Erro ao cadastrar usuario no banco';
    print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
}
```

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Putz  -_-'
É isso mesmo cara, nem tinha reparado. Obrigado!

Comment: Bom que resolveu. Não esquece de marcar minha resposta como escolhida!